# Tween after dragging doesn't start to the drag-end position (with KineticJS)

Tags: html5-canvas, kineticjs

This looks maybe like a bug, don't know if it's really one.

»» http://jsbin.com/ejizib/3/edit

After you move the gray rectangle, there is a tween that changes its position. But the tween starts with the origin position, not the last "drag-end" position.

The tween should start with the drag-end position and go until the `x.` parameter. Why doesn't it work on my jsbin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by instantiating the tween inside 'dragend' and removing tween.reset();

```
rect.on('dragend', function() {
  var tween = new Kinetic.Tween({
    node: rect, 
    duration: 2,
    x: lenght/2
  });
  tween.play();
});
```

http://jsbin.com/ivobup/3/edit